# optimization of creating a form

Tags: delphi, optimization, delphi-2009

To create and show a form takes 10 seconds and i want to shorten the process.

On part is the

```
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
```

Which takes 2 seconds out of the total run time.

Is there a way to shorten the parent create which is the Delphi TForm?
Or Do you know what are the reasons for the increase of time in the call

```
Inherited Create(AOwner);
```

?

update: well I didn't expect for 18 comments and 3 answer :D thank you all for your response.

at the current state i tired a few profiles that around round here, and non lead to a real line of code that was at the code, it was mostly kernel calls or system calls.

so after buying the Delphi XE2 that comes with AQTime , im trying to upgrade the project to Delphi XE2, which now takes a few days.(BIG PROJECT)

ill add information as i get the information from the Profiler.

BTW , being outside of a windows server domain, makes the action twice as much slower. as an inside computer runs under 5 seconds. which is much better, however still slow.

Update2: compiling and running with Delphi XE2 improved almost 20% in time preference over Delphi 2009. AQTime did not yield any useful information.

update3: left xe2 , not stable. went back to delphi 2009 there tried 
in begining of constructor

```
  SendMessage(application.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
```

and in the end of constructor

```
  SendMessage(application.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, -1, 0);
  form.Repaint;
```

reduced 0.1 seconds.

Comment: When I do this the form is created instantly. Clearly your code and my code differ. I know what my code does, but I don't know what your code is.

Comment: @none if you have many, and I mean **many** visual components on the form, it could take a significantly longer time for your application to create the form(s) based on the *.dfm resource(s), so in this case creating the components using code could improve the speed, but it would be an overkill. Are you using multiple form inheritance? some code of what exactly happens in your form's OnCreate would help, I assume it's due to some database connection left open?

Comment: @DorinDuminica Yes, the form contains more then a hundred of visual components. The Constractor itself is huge, and im trying to isolate the problems one at a time.

Comment: @Dorin I see no reason why creating from .dfm would be discernibly slower than the equivalent from code.

Comment: @David if I'm not mistaken, the form's dfm is being parsed at runtime and components are created "on the fly", now, of course, the more you have, the longer it takes, however 10sec. is quite a lot...

Comment: @Dorin Try putting 1000 labels on a TForm and see how long it takes for the form to show. Then tell me parsing the .dfm file is a significant overhead.

Comment: @David nah, I'll lose count and interest at around label #9X (:

Comment: If it takes some seconds, you could pause the application and have a look at the main thread's call stack. (Use Debug DCUs may help to get a better call stack).

Comment: Why does your profiling stop at that call? Dig deeper so you can account for those two seconds with better granularity.

Comment: As it stands now your question is unanswerable because you don't provide enough information about the problem. Edit your question and add as much detail as possible. With the little information you've given the answer could be anything from a misbehaving thread to a seriously underpowered machine.

Comment: @DorinDuminica .dfm are embedded as binary into the .exe - there is no slow text parsing, just quick loading from memory. It has almost no time difference with plain code creation, even for 1000th of components. The issue is not in the serialization, but some initialization code in components or database (in OnCreate, as you stated above).

Comment: @Dorin, creating from code is no different than reading from DFM and creating at runtime, other than the minor overhead of loading the DFM, and it's loaded from a resource and not the disk, so that cost is negligible.

Comment: Where are you calling `inherited Create` from? If you're just using the  `FormCreate` event handler, it's not necessary; the inherited constructor has already been run at that point. Unless you're creating an overridden `constructor Create` (which isn't typically needed), you don't need to call `inherited Create`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - OK, I tried it.  Creating ten forms with 1000 labels each takes ~2.5 sec on my 3GHz box.  It doesn't seem to matter much what kind of drive the EXE is on - it takes the same time on USB flash, SATA spinner and SSD.

Comment: @Ken He's calling `inherited Create` from his constructor.

Comment: @Ken The .dfm file is loaded from disk. An executable is a memory mapped file and the .dfm resource will be page faulted in to memory off the disk.

Comment: @David, it's not a separate disk file, and since I mentioned loading from resource I would have thought you could figure out what I meant. As far as where the call is being made, where is that shown in the code snippet above? He could be calling it from the FormShow event, for all that's said or shown in the question (which is why I was asking). Feeling a little pedantic today? :)

Comment: @KenWhite Which other method routinely has available a variable named `AOwner`?

Comment: @David, any one you'd like to create with a variable by that name. I'm trying to get the poster to provide more info; why are you choosing to quibble over nothing with me? Never mind; I'll leave this thread to you, as you seem to be objecting to anything I comment here. I'll move elsewhere. Sorry to have disturbed you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From experience seeing business forms abusively packed with components:

1. DataBase activity: you have DB components that are active and require DB opening and/or fetching data. The obvious is when your Form contains DBConnections or DataSets left Active at design time, or, sneakier, you have DB aware components (like `TDBEdit`) linked to some DataSources somewhere else (in a DataModule) and these are left Active.
   **Remedy**: Put all your DataSets and Connections in `Active=False` at design time and activate when first needed.
2. Long `OnCreate` events (or call chains): you have too much code or too slow in any of your components `OnCreate` event handlers (or they call/trigger others that are slow/long). Most often seen are file operations like dealing with huge INI Files, heavy XML storage or Excel spreadsheets.
   **Remedy**: Hunt them and try to postpone until you actually need them.
3. Unnecessary Event Handler calls: the events are fired multiple times for no useful reason during the Create (and often calling each other). Use a profiler to detect and count.
   **Remedy**: Deactivate the events until they are useful.

**Last resort trick:** If you cannot make it faster, change the users' perception.
Put a quick opening splash screen with something to look at or read that can occupy the users' attention for about the same time as your MainForm opening.

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler, called AQTime, and find out what is slow.  Nobody here can guess what you're doing that's slow for you.

Answer (score 1):

I read you have many many components on the form. So my guess is that initializing all these components takes up the time not the form creation itself (which usually takes a few ms).

First of all: perhaps you already know this but if not, use a profiler to determine what components on your form give the delay. Are table fillers only called once or multiple times..

If most of those components are controls: you should probably refactor the code and create a some frames for each part. Whenever a part becomes visible for the first can you create the frame needed just in time. This works best when you have tab or something similar when not everything is visible at the same time.

If most components are non visual, you might activate them just in time, create them dynamically if they don't have a property to activate/deactivate them.

If possible, if some queries need to read in data (from database or file or whatever), try to load the data in another thread and blank out some parts of the form until the data is there. Do you need all data right away etc etc.

But still: most important: know what is consuming all that time.